# Http through ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, http

I'm currently working away from home and have only my laptop and phone with me. At my home I have multiple pc's, as well as a Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) server, all running on the local network. I have ssh access to the server.

I would like to set up some port forwarding on the router for a service I just installed on the server. Normally I would do this from within the network by accessing it's web page, however I can't currently do this as I'm not even in the same country!

Rather than try and talk a family member through the process, I was wondering whether I could tunnel my http traffic to/from the router, though my ssh connection?

I'd also like to check the active devices on the network.

Comment: "I'd also like to check the active devices on the network to see if my wife is still sleeping with the next door neighbour." Thats out of scope for us. Also, its possible someone next door can mooch off your wifi. There's a specific spot in the area outside my apartment block I can pick up an AP 25 floors up/

Comment: I've downvoted as this question shows very little done in the way of research by the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is one of the forms of `ssh` forwarding:

Try something like this:

```
$ ssh -L 8080:192.168.0.1:80 user@myremote.host
```

That will forward the local port at 8080 to the address 192.168.1.1:80, as seen from the remote host.

Then you can visit http://localhost:8080

See the [ssh man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Instructions may vary for windows - depending on what his laptop is. Never tried tunneling in android

Comment: You might want to point out that they'll need to be able to SSH to the PC running this (i.e. it'd be run on a linux machine within the home network).

Comment: @djsmiley2kindarkness the OP clearly stated _ I have ssh access to the server._

Answer (score 0):

For checking for 'active' devices on the network, you need to decide if you only care about wirelessly connected devices, or ALL devices, which requires a bit more research.

For Wifi connected devices, that'll normally be listed via your wireless access point, usually having a web interface that you should be able to access using your ssh tunnel.

If you're interested in all devices on the network, you'll likely want to ssh into a linux box, then you can scan your network in a multitude of ways, from using a tool like nmap, or looking at your arp table `arp -a`.